# How do I take out a plane from image, modify it and insert it back?

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I am trying to take out the ground and make grids on it for path mapping and insert it back to the image. Here I am using findhomography and warpPerspective functions to do so. But when I switch the points for inserting back the modified plane, everything except the plane becomes black in the image.

I have tried to do it using an intermediate image but the result is the same.

---

[image]

---

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

struct userdata {
Mat im;
vector<Point2f> points;
};

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* data_ptr)
{
if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
    userdata* data = ((userdata*)data_ptr);
    circle(data - > im, Point(x, y), 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 5, LINE_AA);
    imshow("Image", data - > im);
    if (data - > points.size() < 4) {
        data - > points.push_back(Point2f(x, y));
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// Read source image.
Mat im_src = imread("imagesindoor.jpg");

// Destination image. The aspect ratio of the book is 3/4
Size size(400, 300);
Size size2(im_src.cols, im_src.rows);
Mat im_dst = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC3);

// Create a vector of destination points.
vector<Point2f> pts_dst;

pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(0, 0));
pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(size.width - 1, 0));
pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(size.width - 1, size.height - 1));
pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(0, size.height - 1));

// Set data for mouse event
Mat im_temp = im_src.clone();
userdata data;
data.im = im_temp;

cout << "Click on the four corners of the book -- top left first and" << 
endl
     << "bottom left last -- and then hit ENTER" << endl;

// Show image and wait for 4 clicks.
imshow("Image", im_temp);
// Set the callback function for any mouse event
setMouseCallback("Image", mouseHandler, &data);
waitKey(0);

// Calculate the homography
Mat h = getPerspectiveTransform(data.points, pts_dst);

// Warp source image to destination
warpPerspective(im_src, im_dst, h, size);

// changing clor of im_dst
for (int i = 0; i < im_dst.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < im_dst.cols; j++) {
        //apply condition here

        im_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
Mat p = getPerspectiveTransform(pts_dst, data.points);
warpPerspective(im_dst, im_src, p, size2);

// Show image
//imshow("Image", im_dst);
imshow("Image2", im_src);

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid `using namespace`, especially if you use more than one and rather use `std::` and `cv::`.

Comment: If I understand correctly you collect 4 points of plane using the mouse, then you transform that plane into rectangular image. Here you loose all information about the background. What you need to do is to combine your newly acquired im_src and source image.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I combine these two images?

Comment: can you post the source image and the current result?

Comment: the values for your background are o (black background), Your foreground (the plane) is set to 255 (white foreground). If you have an image of 8 bit values you could just add them. If you want to add grid you just put the selected pixels to 255 and the rest to 0.

Comment: Also a lot of operations in openCV supports using masks, which are basically foreground set to 255 and background set to 0. I don't have time to check this so please if it helps can you write your own answer to your question of what you did.

Comment: Result images would be welcome as well. ;)

Comment: warp your modified image to an emtpy image of same size as your original one, then copy only those pixel to the original one that are in the warped region. You can to that by creating a mask and then using .copyTo(dst, mask)

Answer (score 1):

[addWeighted](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) can be used to blend the current result with the source image to get the expected result.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

struct userdata {
Mat im;
vector<Point2f> points;
};

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* data_ptr)
{
if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
    userdata* data = ((userdata*)data_ptr);
    circle(data-> im, Point(x, y), 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 5, LINE_AA);
    imshow("Image", data->im);
    if (data-> points.size() < 4) {
        data-> points.push_back(Point2f(x, y));
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// Read source image.
Mat im_src = imread("test.png");

// Destination image. The aspect ratio of the book is 3/4
Size size(400, 300);
Size size2(im_src.cols, im_src.rows);
Mat im_dst = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC3);

// Create a vector of destination points.
vector<Point2f> pts_dst;

pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(0, 0));
pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(size.width - 1, 0));
pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(size.width - 1, size.height - 1));
pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(0, size.height - 1));

// Set data for mouse event
Mat im_temp = im_src.clone();
userdata data;
data.im = im_temp;

cout << "Click on the four corners of the book -- top left first and" <<
endl
     << "bottom left last -- and then hit ENTER" << endl;

// Show image and wait for 4 clicks.
imshow("Image", im_temp);
// Set the callback function for any mouse event
setMouseCallback("Image", mouseHandler, &data);
waitKey(0);

// Calculate the homography
Mat h = getPerspectiveTransform(data.points, pts_dst);

// Warp source image to destination
warpPerspective(im_src, im_dst, h, size);

// changing clor of im_dst
for (int i = 0; i < im_dst.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < im_dst.cols; j++) {
        //apply condition here

        im_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
Mat t;
Mat p = getPerspectiveTransform(pts_dst, data.points);

warpPerspective(im_dst, t, p, size2);

// Show image
//imshow("Image", im_dst);
std::cout << "t :" <<t.cols << ", " <<t.rows <<std::endl;

Mat final;
addWeighted(im_src, 0.5, t, 0.5, 0, final);
imshow("Image2", final);



waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```